# checking django empty table object not working

Tags: python, html, django

I've an html page, I'd like to display the search bar only when the passed in table object is NOT empty. But my check is not working properly. Here's the code:

```
<!-- We'll display the search bar only when the user has access to at least one item, otherwise, hide it. -->
{% if item_info %}
Number of entries: {{ item_info|length }}, nothing? {{item_info}}
<section>
    <form method="post" action=".">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" class="search-query span80" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Enter ItemNo to search">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button> 
    </form>
</section>
{% else %}
No item_info.
{% endif%}
```

Here's what I see on the browser:
[image: still enters if branch]

item_info is blank, I think it should go to else branch, however, it entered if branch, any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit after elethan's answer:
I've printed it out to debug, here's the screenshot:
[image: 2nd_img]
So, looks like this item_info is really empty, I didn't see any item_info object gets printed out.

Also, to help debug, here's my view code:

```
def item_info(request):    
    iteminfo= ItemInfo.objects.all().filter(Q(some_query)
    table = ItemInfoTable(iteminfo)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'item_info.html', {'item_info':table,})
```

And here's my table definition:

```
import django_tables2 as tables  
class ItemInfoTable(tables.Table):
    itmno = tables.Column(verbose_name="Item #")
    class Meta:
        model = ItemInfo
        empty_text = "There is no item record."
```

And here's the ItemInfo table it refers to:

```
class ItemInfo(models.Model):
    itmno = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=11L, db_column='ItmNo', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'item_info'
```

Comment: try `{% if item_info.all %}` instead of `{% if item_info %}`

Comment: Is item_info a standard queryset or maybe from a raw sql query call?

Comment: I didn't realize you are using `django-tables2`. I am not familiar with that app, and it makes it difficult for me to test or troubleshoot (though I am not sure if the problem comes from there). Did you make sure to render and load your `table` in your template (there is an example of this on the `django-tables2` github page)? In your case, this would probably be something like `{% load django_tables2 %}` and then 
`{% render_table item_info %}`. Also, in the last line of your `item_info` view function, I think you need to get rid of the `,` after `table`.

Comment: thanks elethan, I got rid of ```,```, but that didn't help. Also, I made sure that I have those ```{% load django_tables2 %} ``` and ```{% render_table item_info %} ``` as well, but still having that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `item_info` is a `RawQuerySet`, try `{% if item_info.all %}` instead of `{% if item_info %}`. `RawQuerySet` does not define a `__bool__()` method, so the instances are always considered `True`. See the warnings in [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) of the docs, repeated below, just in case this link dies in the future:

> While a RawQuerySet instance can be iterated over like a normal
>   QuerySet, RawQuerySet doesn’t implement all methods you can use with
>   QuerySet. For example, **bool**() and **len**() are not defined in
>   RawQuerySet, and thus all RawQuerySet instances are considered True.
>   The reason these methods are not implemented in RawQuerySet is that
>   implementing them without internal caching would be a performance
>   drawback and adding such caching would be backward incompatible.

Comment: Another question just came up, after adding .all, even when ```item_info``` is not empty, it still goes to else branch, I'm wondering why. This ```item_info``` object is from here: ItemInfo.objects.all().filter(Q(some_query))

Comment: any ideas or help please? Thanks!

Comment: @SSun sorry, you are going to have to give me a little while I am away from a computer now.

Comment: Sure, no worries, take your time! I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @SSun, are you sure your query is not returning an empty list? I cannot see anything wrong with your query, but if it really isn't empty, then your if block should run. If you have confirmed that it really isn't empty, can you include your view code in your question as well, so I can get a better idea of what is going on? Also, to debug, try `<h1>item_info: {{ item_info.all }}</h1>` in your template before the `{% if ... %}` to see what it says. If it's not empty you should see something like `[<ItemInfo: ItemInfo object>]`

Comment: sorry for the late response, I've added info per your request to my original question, thanks a lot!